# Map a simplex of ordered probabilities to a scalar

Tags: ordinal-data

Suppose there is an ordinal factor with three levels: low, medium, and high. A model has been trained on historical data to estimate the probabilities of the three categories. For each example, it outputs a simplex $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ where the tree entries correspond to the three levels, respectively.

I am looking for an elegant way to map these three numbers to the unit interval so that the level of concern, from low to high, is properly reflected. I am not sure how to formulate it more precisely and would be grateful for any suggestions on how to think about this problem.

In the case of ordinal regression, there are a latent variable and a number of cut points, and the former solves this problem automatically. However, in my case, the starting point a multiclass classifier that is unaware of the ordering. I wonder if one can create some artificial but sound latent dimension starting from labels and probabilities.

Comment: Explaining why and how a probability distribution has got something to do with a "level of concern" might be a good beginning. Of what exactly should we be concerned?

Comment: I’m thinking about ordinal logistic regression. There you have one latent variable and a number of cut points. I wonder if one could go in the other direction: start with a classified case and the corresponding probability and go to a latent variable.

Comment: I still do not understand whether we talk about supervised or unsupervised learning of the "level of concern". You have not explained yet, what "concern" means in the context of your data.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is present in the fitting procedure itself: some ordinal regression methods, for instance, estimate the values of this map along with two cutoff points to distinguish the three classes.  This suggests the answers to your question may depend on the *model* you are (implicitly?) using to estimate the probabilities and on the procedure you are using to estimate them.

Comment: @whuber, indeed. If it was ordinal regression, it would be done automatically. In my case, it is a nonordinal multiclass classifier. The idea was to use probabilities and labels and mimic somehow that mapping that ordinal regression has.

Comment: Maybe you could use an ordinal regression to suggest the mapping, then.